# Yii client script register script in a line

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I'm using `Yii::app()->clientScript` to register script; In php file, I wrote script in multiply line, but when it register to browser, every script file will put on a line, include my comment, this will make error because everything after `//` will be know as comment.Script after transfer is something like this: `tag.firstChild.onchange=function(){ load_grid(obj); }; } //Comment ....`It has only one line.Please help me.

Update: 
This is an example:

```
$cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;           
    $cs->registerScriptFile('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', CClientScript::POS_HEAD); 

    $cs->registerScript('googlemaps_api','

    function geocode(address, lat_id, lng_id) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();          

        geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {                                      
                $("#"+lat_id).val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $("#"+lng_id).val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            } else alert("'.Yii::t('views/config/edit_store_locations_options','ERROR_GEOCODE_ADDRESS').'");        
        });                 
    }
    ', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

Comment: show us how exactly you register, and what is the content of the file being registered.

Answer (score 4):

I find the embedding of inline JS code into my registerScript() function call very inconvenient, and opt to use heredoc format with success.

```
$script = <<<EOD

    function geocode(address, lat_id, lng_id) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();          

        geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {                                      
                $("#"+lat_id).val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $("#"+lng_id).val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            } else alert("'.Yii::t('views/config/edit_store_locations_options','ERROR_GEOCODE_ADDRESS').'");        
        });                 
    }

EOD;

    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('googlemaps_api', $script, CClientScript::POS_HEAD);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that is normal and somewhat desired behavior. Why not use /**/ to put in your comments, in this way everything will work properly.